# What to call someone who apologizes unnecessarily

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What word or phrase can be used to describe someone who is quick to apologize even if they probably did not do do anything wrong?

It could be for different reasons:

- Maybe the person immediately assumes that something which is said to them is meant as criticism, even if it's not.
- Maybe the person operates under the assumption that any criticism they receive must be legitimate, even if it often isn't.
- Maybe they apologize pre-emptively *just in case* they did something wrong, even though no one said anything.
- Or any other reason which would make their apologies come across as too frequent or too easily given.

Comment: An *obsequious* person might apologize often and more  than necessary. You might  also check out synonyms of obsequious.

Answer (score 4):

The adjective you are looking for is very simple

> [**apologetic**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/apologetic)
>
> 3. willing or eager to apologise.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following terms carry the connotations you are referring to:

***[submissive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/submissive)***:

> - inclined or ready to submit or yield to the authority of another; unresistingly or humbly obedient.

***[deferential](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deference):***

> - that shows respectful submission or yields to the judgment, opinion, will, etc., of another.

(Dictionary.com)